# disable alphabetically sorting in javadoc

Tags: javadoc

Is there any way that things (e.g. methods) in javadoc don't get rearranged alphabetically? I just want them to appear in the order they also appear in the sourcecode to keep a certain flow when reading through the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the methods themselves (in the *Method Detail* section) stay in the same order as they are in the source code.

Just the *Method Summary* is sorted alphabetically, and I don't think you can change this.

Comment: Thanks - I haven't realised that so far (I'm quite new to javadoc). To clearify my question: I actually meant the Summary sections - it would be kind of annoying not to be able to change this behavior ...

Comment: You could patch the standard doclet (or write a new doclet) to omit the sorting. I find it quite useful to be able to find a method by name, though.

Comment: Can you maybe tell me where the standard doclet is located?